# JSON equivalent of INSERT...ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE, and increase current value on existent

Tags: mysql

I have a situation like this, simplified:

```
CREATE TABLE `user_points` (
  `date` date NOT NULL,
  `user_id` mediumint(8) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `points` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`date`, `user_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

so, if today a user earns a point, I make:

```
INSERT INTO user_points (date, user_id, points) VALUES (CURDATE(),?,1) 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE points=points+1;
```

Now, imagine I want to store these points into a JSON field, that contains not only points but it may contain other properties (these properties are dynamic, some clients will never use any, other will use a lot of them, that's why I like JSON)

So, instead of adding to `points`, I want to set `$.points` on a `data` column.

Is it possible to make a single query that does this?

- If there is no row with such *date* and *user_id*, insert a new row with data=`{"points": 1}`
- If there is a row and *data* is null, `SET data="{"points": 1}"`
- If there is a row with some json, but not $.data, `JSON_SET(data, '$.points', 1)`
- if there is a row and some $.points, increase the points by one.

I tried:

```
SELECT JSON_SET('{"a": 1, "l": 2}', '$.points', 
    JSON_EXTRACT('{"a": 1, "l": 2}', '$.points')+1) AS 'Data';
```

but it doesn't work (because NULL + 1 = NULL instead of 1)

EDIT: that can be solved with COALESCE, but I'm not sure it's the best solution:

```
SELECT JSON_SET('{"a": 1, "l": 2}', '$.points', 
    COALESCE(JSON_EXTRACT('{"a": 1, "l": 2}', '$.points'), 0)+1) AS 'Data';
```

the full query would be:

```
INSERT INTO user_points (date, user_id, data) VALUES (CURDATE(),?,'{"points":1}') 
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE data=JSON_SET(data, '$.points', 
    COALESCE(JSON_EXTRACT(data, '$.points'), 0)+1);
```

Comment: Instead of using JSON, why don't you model out these properties using an EAV model? That way, you can stay relational and still have an extensible system.

Comment: reading the data happens much more frequently than writing, and having all the data in a single row is better, for example I want to read all the data for all the users for today

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the working solution I found so far, it needs COALESCE twice (in case `data` is null, and in case `data.points` is null:

```
INSERT INTO user_data (date, user_id, data) VALUES (CURDATE(), ?, '{"points":1}')
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE data=JSON_SET(COALESCE(data, '{}'), '$.points', 
    COALESCE(JSON_EXTRACT(data, '$.points'), 0)+1);
```

I wonder why it adds a `.0`..

[image]